# Inserting into table the values returned from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a procedure which has a select statement as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_test
as 
SELECT  * from SOURCETABLE
```

Can I insert into a temp table by executing the stored procedure pr_test by any chance?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current SQL attempts and explain what is not working and where you are stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INSERT EXEC`

```
 declare @t results (field1 int, ....)

 insert @t (field1,...)
 exec pr_test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_test 
as
begin

CREATE TABLE #TibetanYaks(
YakID int,
YakName char(30) )

INSERT INTO #TibetanYaks (YakID, YakName)
SELECT  YakID, YakName
FROM    dbo.Yaks
WHERE   YakType = 'Tibetan'

-- Do some stuff with the table

drop table #TibetanYaks


end
```